# What is the meaning of the term "backgrounding against someone"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

Like in [this tweet](https://twitter.com/vanOnselenP/status/1364712775126114314):

> Last week I revealed the PMO was **backgrounding against** Brittany Higgins partner.

I could not find the meaning of this term. What are the meaning and origin?

Comment: It seems to refer the investigation  of a rape which allegedly occurred in the PMO a couple of years ago. In rape cases, a victim's background is often used  against them.

Comment: Is it correct to assume that "PMO" means "project management office"?

Comment: @HotLicks PMO = Prime Minister's Office (i.e. the *staff* comprising the PMO). Brittany alleges she was raped in a government minister's office several years ago but didn't make a complaint for fear it would destroy her political career. She's now gone public, and the Prime Minister looks a fool for admitting that none of his staff told him about this serious allegation, even though many knew about it. The tweet alleges the PMO is trying to discredit the victim by digging up dirt on her partner – i.e. using *background* information as a political weapon.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question for lack of research. This use of *background* can be found in any good dictionary. MW defines the verb as "to provide with background", and the particular kind of [background (the noun)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/background) here is definition 3b, either (1) "the circumstances or events antecedent to a phenomenon or development" or (2)  "information essential to understanding of a problem or situation". "Backgrounding against (someone)" is readily understandable as "using someone's background against them."